# intel x86 emulator accelerator ( HAXM ) not compatible with window

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, android-emulator

I try to download Xamarin for emulator Androids devices so I can debug web page on them . by download Visual studio and run Tools/Android/Android SDK Manager

but when I try to run on of the emulator I got :

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.

I find HAXM in the `Android SDK Manger/Extras/intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` but next to it I saw "not compatible with Windows"

So How can I install it ?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research I solved it.

should disable `Hyper-V` on windows 10 ( HAXM want to work exclusively.. )  if it already enabled (example for Dockers )

And I found that can download HAXM from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

: `right click on Start/Program and Futures/Turn Window features on of off/Hyper-V`